# SimpleXML: can't fetch data from XML file

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

I am trying to use the DELL API to fetch warranty information from our products. DELL provides an XML file that I want to extract the end of warranty date from.

Location of the XML file: https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags?svctags=XXXXXX1&apikey=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

[Note: svctags and apikey obfuscated]

Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags?svctags=XXXXXXX1&apikey=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
print_r($xml->GetAssetWarrantyResult->{'a:Response'}->{'a:DellAsset'}->{'a:Warranties'}->{'a:Warranty'}->{'a:EndDate'});
```

This is not working. I get an empty page when executing this code. Can anybody explain why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `file_get_contents()` and then load the string return from `file_get_contents()` into XML?

Answer (score 0):

you can used curl, For ex:

```
$url = "https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags?svctags=1RP22W1&apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e"
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: This seems to return nothing, nor with "echo", nor with "print_r"

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted more.

get url: https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags.json?svctags="
        +tag+"&apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e

Then parse the response in (javascript). 
In python you could also read each line page.readlines() and use encode=json.loads(data) to start reading the result like a dictionary.